# I'm getting a NullPointerException when I click a button on my Android app

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I’m working on a simple Quiz app where the user is presented a question and can select either True or False to answer the question. I added a “Show Answer” button, but when I click on that button I’m getting the following NullPointerException. I think I'm  missing something in my activity_cheat.xml but I can't figure out what.

```
05-31 19:30:59.238    5978-5978/com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.geoquiz E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.geoquiz, PID: 5978
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(int)' on a null object reference
            at com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.geoquiz.CheatActivity$1.onClick(CheatActivity.java:33)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5197)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20926)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

CheatActivity.java

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.geoquiz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class CheatActivity extends Activity {
    private boolean mAnswerIsTrue;

    private TextView mAnswerTextView;
    private Button mShowAnswer;

    public static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE =  "com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.answer_is_true";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat);

        mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false);


        mShowAnswer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.showAnswerButton);
        mShowAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mAnswerIsTrue) {
                    mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.true_button);
                } else {
                    mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.false_button);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

activity_cheat.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
              android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:text="@string/warning_text_view" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answerTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/showAnswerButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/show_answer_button" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mAnswerTextView` is never initialized. That's why you get the NPE.

add

```
mAnswerTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answerTextView);
```

before

```
 if (mAnswerIsTrue)
```

Comment: done. stackoverflow wasn't letting me accept it earlier. thnx

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to bind mAnswerTextView with the UI:

Add

```
mAnswerTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answerTextView);
```

after the line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat);
```

Answer (score 6):

`mAnswerTextView` is null.
Add,

`mAnswerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerTextView);`

before your onClickListener.